# JAVA-Read a file in java and write them into n different files based on unique words

Tags: java, java-io

Input to the program would be start and end position of the unique word in each line from db and a text file.

For example:
for the below input file start position is 0 and end position is 6 which is ABCDEF,store this value and compare with the first 6 characters in second line ifs its same copy them into same file else copy them into another file.For every file there can be 'n' no unique words ,n different files need to be created dynamically.positions will change file to file.The file size can be more than 10gb

Original input file:
originalfile.txt

> ABCDEF aksjlnf  woeirf 234 1234
>
> FJHIJK sdfdf  3412344      124
>
> ABCDEF asdhgbfl     3   agagd
>
> FJHIJK agagafg 1  agag
>
> output should be:splitfile1.txt
>
> ABCDEF aksjlnf  woeirf 234 1234
>
> ABCDEF asdhgbfl     3   agagd
>
> splitfile2.txt FJHIJK sdfdf  3412344      124
>
> FJHIJK sdfdf  3412344      124

Comment: You forgot to add your code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look `String.split(String regex)` and after you split the lines into `ArrayList`s, then you can control everything you want.

[String Split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm)

[Java - ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Just read and learn them; then send us your works, after you do that, we can help you better. Otherwise, it means we do your homework or something and you didn't learn Java.